# imprimir cantidad de columnas de una busqueda mysql en fpdf

Tags: php, loops, while, fpdf

Tengo una consulta de `MySQL` en la cual pueden haber x cantidad radios de comunicaciones almacenados allí, la tabla me imprime perfecto si lo hago sin el contador, pero como es necesario saber cuantos radios hay de acuerdo a la consulta, necesito que en la primera casilla salga el contador, es decir, si hay 10 radios que salga 1, 2, 3... 10

Primero capturo cuantos radios hay de acuerdo a la localización y efectivamente esta bien por que ya imprimí la variable `$total` y si hay 15 radios, me imprime 15, he aquí el código:

```
//averiguo cuantos radios hay
$total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dispositivos WHERE localizacion ='$localizacion_seleccionada'"));


/* 
esto es lo que intenté, pero al momento de imprimir, si hay 13 radios efectivamente me sale 1,2,3... hasta el 13  y vuelve a empezar, es decir imprime los 13 radios una y otra vez
*/

while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
{
        for ($i=1; $i < $total; $i++) 
    {
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,$i,1,0,'C'); // en esta casilla numero del radio
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,$resultado['marca'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,$resultado['tipo'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(15,10,$resultado['id'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(22,10,$resultado['serie'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(25,10,$resultado['modelo'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(10,10,$resultado['frecuencia'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(7,10,$resultado['bateria'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(7,10,$resultado['antena'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(7,10,$resultado['gancho'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(7,10,$resultado['cargador'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(7,10,$resultado['fuente'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(130,10,$resultado['comentarios'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Ln();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este bucle te sobra:  `for ($i=1; $i < $total; $i++)`

Simplemente pon un contador dentro del bucle `while` y listo.

```
var i = 0;
while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
  i = i + 1;
  $pdf->Cell(20,10,$i,1,0,'C'); 
  ...
  $pdf->Cell(130,10,$resultado['comentarios'],1,0,'C'); 
  $pdf->Ln(); 
}
```